# How to Get Page 2 / Paginated RSS Feed with Custom Permalink Structure?

Tags: permalinks, pagination, rss

I'm trying to get pagination working for my RSS feed.

The issue is that my permalink setup is a custom structure: `/%postname%`.

- With permalinks back to *default*, `/?feed=rss2&paged=2` works.
- But with permalinks on my custom structure, `/?feed=rss2&paged=2` redirects to `/feed?paged=2` which *does not work*.
- Additionally, with the custom structure, `/page/2/feed` does not work (it redirects to `/feed`!) although `/page/2` works for end-users reading the site.

Is this a bug? I've disabled all plugins and went back to the default theme to confirm the problem.

Long story short, how do you get RSS feed pagination with a custom permalink structure in place?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As an update. It turns out that what I'm trying to do is outside of RSS's specification. So the short answer is "don't do that, use an API".

But had I *wanted* to hack around that spec, I could

- Use the Custom Permalinks plugin
- Go back to the default permalink mode in the site's settings
- Then the `paged` parameter would work for a custom RSS feed in my theme.

Overall I'm going with the API, and will just make sure it's secure.